# Is this a valid way to create doubly linked-list?

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [context switch during doubly linked list creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060456/context-switch-during-doubly-linked-list-creation)

I was reading **[The Design of the UNIX Operating System (Maurice Bach)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997)**.

He gives the following example of a **doubly linked-list**.

```
struct queue{
    //pointers (back and forward)
    //other data
}*bp, *bp1

bp1->forp = bp->forp; //1

bp1->backp = bp; //makes sense
bp->forp = bp1; //makes sense

bp1->forp->backp = bp1; //2
```

I can't understand the purpose of the statements marked `1` and `2`. `1` seems wrong, `2` looks to be redundant.

Is this a valid way to create a doubly linked-list?

Comment: It's valid code to insert `bp1` after `bp` in a doubly-linked list, provided that `bp->forp` isn't `NULL` at the start.

Comment: @BoPersson My question is actually regarding the creation of the linked-list and not the context-switch involved.

Comment: Why is the first word in your question "valid"?? Did you think that without that, people would suggest *invalid* ways to create lists?

Comment: @KerrekSB I meant "Is this a valid way to...". :)

Comment: Hah, a duplicate that's really a duplicate

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It isn't a duplicate! :D That question is about the context switch, this is about how the code is even valid in the first place.

Comment: @Cthulhu spoiling my fun

Comment: What is the code for? Inserting an element? Creating an empty list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct.

`bp` is a doubly linked list.
You want to insert `bp1` into `bp` as the second item in the list (that is what the code does).

To do that you need to set 4 pointers:

`bp1->forp` should point to the second item in the list, `bp->forp`  (`//1` above)

`bp1->backp` should point to the first item in the list, `bp`

`bp->forp` should point to the inserted item, `bp1`

The back pointer of the second item, `bp1->forp->backp` should point to the inserted item, `bp1`.  (`//2` above)

**Edit:**

Let's call the structs A, B, C, D...
The list (pointed to by `bp` consists of A, C, D... before the insert. We want to insert B (pointed to by `bp1`.
`<->` denotes the forward and backwards pointers.

Before:

```
bp --> A <-> C <-> D <-> E <-> ...
bp1--> B
```

After:

```
bp--> A <-> B <-> C <-> D <-> E <-> ...
```

Comment: Didn't approach it thinking there was already a list in place. Makes sense now. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was why it didn't make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting an item into a doubly-linked list, you have to change the two pointers pointing from the new element and the two pointers pointing to the new element.

The line marked with `//1` sets the next-pointer of the new one to the next after the insertion position. The line marked `//2` sets the previous-pointer of the next element to the new element, completing the bidirectional link between them.

Note that this code will segfault when the new element is added to the end of the list. In that case `bp1->forp` will be NULL, so `bp1->forp->backp` will attempt to dereference a null pointer.

**Edit**

at the beginning:

```
bp  ->forp  = next
next->backp = bp  
bp1 ->forp  = null
bp1 ->backp = null 

The list looks like this. bp and next are linked, bp1 is outside of the list.

       /---\/            
    [bp]   [next]         [bp1]
      /\---/
```

after line `//1`

```
bp  ->forp  = next
next->backp = bp   
bp1 ->forp  = next
bp1 ->backp = null 

the forward pointer of bp1 points to the next element, but nothing points
to bp1 yet:

        /------------\/    
       /        /----\/
    [bp]    [bp1]    [next] 
      /\------------/
```

before line `//2`

```
bp  ->forp  = bp1
bp1 ->forp  = next
bp1 ->backp = bp 
next->backp = bp   

The link from next to bp1 hasn't been updated yet - it still points to bp:

      /---\/  /---\/            
  [bp]    [bp1]   [next]
    /\----/       /
    /\-----------/
```

after line `//2`

```
bp  ->forp  = bp1
bp1 ->forp  = next
bp1 ->backp = bp 
next->backp = bp   

The list is linked correctly:

      /---\/  /---\/            
   [bp]   [bp1]   [next]
    /\----/  /\---/
```

Comment: I added some ASCII arts to illustrate. I hope this helps you to understand what is going on (looks better in the source view).

Comment: "Note that this code will segfault when the new element is added to the end of the list. In that case bp1->forp will be NULL" -- assuming that null pointers are used to indicate end-of-list. It's possible that they aren't, and instead the linked list is stored as a loop. I haven't read the book to know one way or the other, though, so apologies if you have and it is null :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Is this a valid way to create a doubly linked-list?`

**No, right now as is, this code will just give you a segmentation fault. It's pretty obviously why if you add the following lines after each step:

```
printf("bp = %#x\n\tbp->forp=%#x\n\tbp->backp=%#x\n", bp, bp->forp, bp->backp);
printf("bp1 = %#x\n\tbp1->forp=%#x\n\tbp1->backp=%#x\n", bp1, bp1->forp, bp1->backp);
```

First, you'd need to allocate and initialize your structures:

```
bp = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
bp->forp = NULL;
bp->backp = NULL;
bp1 = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
bp1->forp = NULL;
bp1->backp = NULL;
```

Then we print the values you'd see something like this:

```
bp = 0x804b008
    bp->forp=0     //forward and back pointers are not pointing anywhere, good start
    bp->backp=0
bp1 = 0x804b018
    bp1->forp=0
    bp1->backp=0
```

After these lines:

```
    bp1->forp = bp->forp;  //bp1->forp is pointing no where (NULL), neither is bp->forp
                           // so this does nothing really... 
    bp1->backp = bp;
    bp->forp = bp1;
```

Now you'd have something like:

```
bp = 0x804b008
    bp->forp=0x804b018
    bp->backp=0
bp1 = 0x804b018
    bp1->forp=0
    bp1->backp=0x804b008
```

So as you said, that makes sense. Now what we try the next line?

```
bp1->forp->backp = bp1; //2
       ^
       |
       +------ That's NULL, and a seg fault.
```

You need one more line before this:

```
bp1->forp-> = bp;
bp1->forp->backp = bp1;
```

**Now** you're good to go.

**Assuming an initially empty list.

Comment: +1. Thanks, your code is the `completed` version of what the book mentioned, but the author was merely illustrating his point. The thing made sense, when I considered `bp` to be a pre-existing doubly-linked list as the accepted answer states :D

Comment: @Cthulhu - Ah, but there's the problem. Your question says `is this a valid way to create a doubly linked list`, and the answer is no. It's not a valid way to create a doubly linked list. You should have asked `is this a valid way to insert into a doubly linked list`. As per your question in its current form. I am the correct answer. ;)

Comment: Yes, that would make you the correct answer! Will award bounty when I can :) I didn't realize it was insertion till @KlasLindback mentioned it. My mistake with the question.